# React: URL.revokeObjectURL() does not clear data when file changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, createobjecturl

I create a `image preview` in `React`.

The `preview image` change every time `input` change:

```
const [src, setSrc] = useState('')
const [file, setFile] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
  setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(file))

  return () => {
    src && URL.revokeObjectURL(src)
  }
}, [file])
```

I open image in new tab. Then I change file, The `old image` till exist when I reload it.

What am I wrong?